# How to keep process without "main thread" in python3 multiprocessing?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Multiprocessing in python starts a new process.

Within that new process, I create 2 new threads and do nothing else in the "main thread" that started the new process, it seems that the process is gone.

Example:

```
new_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=new_proc_main, name=yyy)
new_process.start()

def new_proc_main():
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=xxxx, name=thread1)
    thread1.start()
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=xxxx, name=thread2)
    thread2.start()
```

How can I keep the new process alive while threads 1 & 2 run?

Comment: You didn't set the `daemon` flag on those threads so the main thread does a `.join()` on both of them before exiting. So,the main thread did wait. Perhaps those child threads raised exceptions and exited? You could add a try/except block to `xxxx` and print a message if they fail.

Comment: What does setting `daemon` flag do? I read the doc but it does not make sense. If I read this doc correctly, even if thread1 & 2 are marked as daemon, the process will exit since those are the only threads left in the process. Am I right?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html
"A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left. The initial value is inherited from the creating thread. The flag can be set through the daemon property or the daemon constructor argument."

Comment: The threading package keeps track of your threads in the background. When you exit, it will go through the list doing `t.join()` for each of them. Since `join` waits for the thread to end, this makes the main thread wait for them to complete. if you set the `daemon` flag before starting the thread, the package doesn't track the thread and doesn't attempt the join at the end.

Comment: Consider writing a simple working example that we can try ourselves. Then we can make sure we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: I wrote a test program and it looks like process created by multiprocessing.Process does not do the join automatically.

Comment: Interesting. Is it small enough to post here?

Comment: Yes, I posted as an answer to this question

Comment: and it has the platform. thanks.

Comment: interesting to know that it works on windows! but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a test program. This is Python 3.6.2 on MacOS

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def new_main():
    import threading
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=dummy_main)
    my_thread.start()
    my_thread.join()

def dummy_main():
    while True:
        print("thread running")
        time.sleep(1)

print("start process")
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=new_main)
p.start()
```

The key is that I have to have `my_thread.join()`.
If I do not have that, the program exits immediately.